# ruby metaprogramming alternative to eval

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I have the following statement which does work although it uses eval:

```
  def resource_name
    self.class.to_s.match(/(.+)Controller/)[1].singularize
  end

  def collection
    @collection ||= eval "#{resource_name}.all(sort: [[:name, :asc]])"
  end
```

Is there a better way of doing this that does not use eval?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Object#send` instead, after you constantize the resource name: http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-send

Comment: better use `public_send` instead of `send`, it prevents you from calling private methods like `system`

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly you're trying to go from the string 'Product' to the constant `Product`, so you could just use

```
Object.const_get(resource_name)
```

If you're using Rails, you can also use `constantize` which has the advantage of understanding things like `Module::SomeClass`